# Google AutoML "Unable to import file"

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I have an unsatisfying error message when I try to import an image to my AutoML dataset.

Can anyone from Google (or else) help me?

I can provide more details (project-id, dataset-id, etc.) on a more private channel.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDvTx.png)

Comment: While there does not come any response I decided to delete the dataset. But this is also not possible.

`Exception while handling your request: Internal error encountered.. When reporting refer to this issue by its tracking code tc_243764`

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening an issue in public [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=0) someone should get back to you with request for more details.